# Algebraic Rule Explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain to me why $\dfrac{3^{n-1}}{3^n}$ is equal to $\dfrac{1}{3}$?

Also are there any videos or resources that you can provide to teach me some of these rules?

Thanks you.

Comment: In general $\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}$.

Comment: I've written a prototype for a web page that you may find helpful. http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3}{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3}=\frac13,$$ no ?

Comment: @amWhy: the case $n=7$ is quite sufficient to allow anyone to generalize as the pattern is obvious. This is a kind of answer "without words", IMO more efficient than other algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @amWhy: cheers !

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{3^{n-1}}{3^n}=3^{n-1-n}=3^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\frac{3^{n-1}}{3^n}=\frac{3^{n-1}}{3 \cdot 3^{n-1}} \\ =\frac{1}{3}.$$
The same technique can be used to prove the general formula

$$\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m}.$$

Answer (score 0):

In general 
$$
x^b / x^c = x^{b - c}
$$

now take $x=3$,$b = n-1$, and $c = n$ and you will get

$$
\frac{3^{n-1}}{3^n} = 3^{(n -1) - n} = 3^{-1} = \frac{1}{3}
$$